# Orderd Monero before update

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain

I bought monero before the update. And did not receive them. After i updated the wallet gui they still didnt appear. What can i do?
If theres somene german speaking please explain it to me in german. Thank you :)

Comment: You're probably synced to the wrong (alternative) chain. Therefore, you should be able to resolve your issue with that ^ guide.